# Getting false positive trigger signal from libpqxx await_notification()

Tags: c++, postgresql, timescaledb, libpq, libpqxx

The code below uses `libpqxx` C++ library to listen to two trigger signals coming from a TimescaleDB database. There are two infinite loops to wait until a trigger occurs.

```
while (true){
    conn.await_notification();
    spdlog::info("channel1_updated");
}
```

```
while (true){
    conn.await_notification();
    spdlog::info("channel2_updated");
}
```

The issue is although no trigger is generated, I get false positive messages, and `channel1_updated` and `channel2_updated` get printed without any signal generated as if `conn.await_notification()` did not behave properly. I am expecting it to simply block the code until a signal is received.

```
#include "pqxx/config-public-compiler.h"
#include <cctype>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

#include <pqxx/internal/header-pre.hxx>
#include <pqxx/internal/wait.hxx>
#include <pqxx/internal/header-post.hxx>
#include <pqxx/notification>
#include <pqxx/transaction>
#include <pqxx/transactor>
#include <thread>

#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"
#include "spdlog/cfg/env.h"
#include "spdlog/fmt/ostr.h" 

class PostgresChannelListener final : public pqxx::notification_receiver {
    bool m_done;
public:
    int backend_pid;

    explicit PostgresChannelListener(pqxx::connection &conn, std::string Name) :
            pqxx::notification_receiver(conn, Name), m_done(false) {}

    void operator()(std::string const &, int be_pid) override {
        m_done = true;
        this->backend_pid = be_pid;
        spdlog::info("Received notification: {} pid=", channel(), be_pid);
    }

    bool done() const { return m_done; }
};

int waitForChannelUpdated(const std::string& channel){
    try {
        pqxx::connection conn("dbname=postgres user=postgres password=password hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432");
        if (conn.is_open()) {
            spdlog::info("Opened database successfully: {}", conn.dbname());
            spdlog::info("PostgreSQL server version: {}", conn.server_version());
        } else {
            spdlog::error("Failed to open database");
            return 1;
        }

        PostgresChannelListener L{conn, channel};

        pqxx::perform([&conn, &L] {
            pqxx::work tx{conn};
            tx.exec0("NOTIFY " + tx.quote_name(L.channel()));
            tx.commit();
        });

        while (true) {
            conn.await_notification();
            spdlog::info(channel);
        }

        conn.close();
        spdlog::info("Closed database successfully");

    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        spdlog::error("Error: {}", e.what());
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}


int main() {

    std::thread threadChannel1([](){
        waitForChannelUpdated("channel1_updated");
    });

    std::thread threadChannel2([](){
        waitForChannelUpdated("channel2_updated");
    });

    threadChannel1.join();
    threadChannel2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Per the [docs](https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/7.0.0/a00809.html#af40df333a37b9ba5f32d7ce399c397ca), "The wait may also be terminated by other events, such as the connection to the backend failing." Maybe something like this is happening? The docs are otherwise sparse on what "other events" may be.

Comment: Is there any other blocking mechanism to simply waits indefinite until a trigger arrives?